# Two items get selected in listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I'm trying to implement a custom listview. Everything works fine until I use a  `if ()` statement inside the `getView()` method

Without the `if()` condition a single item gets selected when I select an item but when I add the `if()` condition, the views are displayed properly but two items (non-adjacent) get selected (1st and last 1st or and second-last, any such combination).

```
View getView(...){
    ....
    if (!item.getPriceTo().equals(""))
                priceToTV.setText(item.getPriceTo());
            else
                priceToTV.setText(item.getPriceFrom());
    return view;
}
```

Also I'm using saving the previous view to show the selection so the current selection has a red_border and when it is selected a black_border is set to it.:

```
subItemsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Log.d("New Order", "........");
                if (previousViewOfSubItems != null && previousViewOfSubItems != view) {
                    previousViewOfSubItems.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_border);
                    if (quantity.getText().toString().equals("xx") || quantity.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
                        viewForVisibility.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layoutForQuantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
                if (previousViewOfSubItems == view)
                    return;
                previousViewOfSubItems = view;
                previousViewOfSubItems.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_border);
                viewForVisibility = previousViewOfSubItems.findViewById(R.id.viewForVisibility);
                viewForVisibility.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layoutForQuantity = (LinearLayout) previousViewOfSubItems.findViewById(R.id.layoutForQuantity);
                layoutForQuantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                quantity = (TextView) previousViewOfSubItems.findViewById(R.id.subTypeQuantity);

            }
        });
```

Comment: its beacause it listview reuses view to display items, once the first view is scrolled out the the same view is reused to display the view at bottom of the listview. instead of comparing the view try compairingthe position of the view clicked .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`previousViewOfSubItems = view;` seems to be causing the problem,

In Listviews with adapter you should avoid saving view instances, because views are reused by adapters so view can be same for two rows so rather than saving view instance's reference use [`ViewHolder` Design pattern](https://github.com/metova/design-patterns-sample/blob/master/Android/Sample-Android/designpatterns/src/main/java/com/metova/designpatterns/ui/ViewHolder.java) and use view tagging

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ViewHolder Pattern and view tagging to properly identify every view in different position. ListView always recycle the view instead of re-inflating the view again and again.

You can refer to [Android Training documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) on how to implement ViewHolder pattern.

Comment: Yes I know ListView recycles the view but this is the first time I have experienced this problem.

Comment: It depends on the complexity of the view. If you have simple view, the bug may not occur. But, it is advisable to us viewholder pattern in any circumstances.

Comment: This did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

ListViews recycle the views in the list. so as you scroll, top views are reused and content replaced using the methods.

Where you set background to Red etc, use Else statements to set it back to your default black.

Answer (score 0):

its beacause it listview reuses view to display items, once the first view is scrolled out the the same view is reused to display the view at bottom of the listview. instead of comparing the view try compairing the position of the view clicked

Answer (score 0):

I have explained about this abnormal behavior in my [blog](http://blog.inapptext.com/recyclerview-creating-dynamic-lists-and-grids-in-android-1/#responding_user_actions) on recyclerview you refer that to solve this problem.

use pojo class to get the status and update the view accordingly